# Basic Java Hangman

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I am just starting to learn Java as my first programming language.

In class we were assigned to make a basic Hangman game with the use of a while and for loops.

**What I have so far**

When the user inputs the first guess it does recognize that that characters that he/she guessed was corrected but just continues on and stating that I have guessed an incorrect letter!

Help would be very appreciated!! My question is what am I doing wrong in my code? I need the program to tell the user if his guess is right or wrong.

My code:

```
import cs1.Keyboard;

public class Hangman {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int guessCount = 0;
        int correctGuess = 0;
        boolean foundIt;
        boolean solved;
        char guess, answer;
        String word;
            
        System.out.println("Welcome to HangMan!");
        System.out.println("Please enter a word for the opponent to guess!");
        word = Keyboard.readString();
        while (guessCount <= 6) {
            System.out.println("Please enter any letter A-Z as your guess!");
            guess = Keyboard.readChar();
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                if (guess == word.charAt(i)) {
                    System.out.println("You have guessed a correct letter!");
                    correctGuess++;
                    System.out.println("Correct Guess Count: "
                                        + correctGuess);
                    solved = false;
                }
                else if (guess != word.charAt(i)) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry! That is an incorrect guess! " 
                                       + "Please try again!");
                    guessCount++;
                    System.out.println("Guess Count: " + guessCount);
                    solved = false;
                }
            }
            if (correctGuess == word.length()) {
                solved = true;
                System.out.println("Congratulations! " + 
                                   "You have guessed the word!");
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far and here is the output

```
Welcome to HangMan!
Please enter a word for the opponent to guess!
hello
Please enter any letter A-Z as your guess!
l
Sorry! That is an incorrect guess! Please try again!
Guess Count: 1
Sorry! That is an incorrect guess! Please try again!
Guess Count: 2
You have guessed a correct letter!
Correct Guess Count: 1
You have guessed a correct letter!
Correct Guess Count: 2
Sorry! That is an incorrect guess! Please try again!
Guess Count: 3
Please enter any letter A-Z as your guess!
```

Comment: OK, what is your question?

Comment: My question is what am I doing wrong in my code? I need the program to tell the user if his guess is right or wrong not just output all that BS. I have done research on the charAt to make sure I was using it correctly and I think I am

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You compare the `guess` to every character in the `String` and then display the message *for every character*. Instead, you should write a method that returns a count of characters that match the input (this also handles words that have repeats of letters). So,

```
private static int countOf(String in, char ch) {
    int count = 0;
    for (char c : in.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == ch) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Then you can call it like,

```
guess = Keyboard.readChar();
int count = countOf(word, guess);
if (count > 0) {
  System.out.println("You have guessed a correct letter!");
  correctGuess += count;
} else {
  System.out.println("Sorry! That is an inncorrect guess! Please try again!");
}
guessCount++;
```

**Edit** To do it without a second method you could use,

```
guess = Keyboard.readChar();
int count = 0;
for (char c : in.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == guess) {
        count++;
    }
}
if (count > 0) {
  System.out.println("You have guessed a correct letter!");
  correctGuess += count;
} else {
  System.out.println("Sorry! That is an inncorrect guess! Please try again!");
}
guessCount++;
```

And, since you haven't used the [`for-each`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) -

```
char[] chars = in.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (chars[i] == guess) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: See I have not learned the part where you made a whole new method! Looks like a different kind of for loop that I have never worked with before. I will try to incorporate and learn it! Thanks!

Comment: You don't really need a whole new method.  You should be able to do this with a loop contained inside your loop.  You'll need to count how many letters in the word matched the letter that was input, and then if it's zero, print the "incorrect guess" message.

Comment: Sweet! I just looked up the toCharArray and that will be very useful and makes a lot more sense!! Only problem now is it is sasy ch cannot be resolved to a variable Not sure if that is just a fill in that you just added or if im missing somthing :/

Comment: @NicLaQuatra Edited. Yes, that should have been `guess`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to ask user input every time you finish an response to update the loop.

Your variable guess was never updated inside the loop, that is why it is running into infinite loop. You have update the guess variable as well inside the loop.

Comment: Edit: the simplest way is to ask for user input again with in the loop until they guess the entire word right.

Comment: So will that require more for loops?